# Constraints are not allowed on not generic environment error while casting

Tags: c#, xamarin, casting

I am trying to cast Java lang object to particular class type(Account).

```
public static T Cast(Object obj) where T : class
{
    var propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Instance");
    return propertyInfo == null ? null : propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null) as T;
}
```

It is throwing an error

> Constraints are not allowed on not generic environment.

I've been stuck here for the past two days.

Comment: You have not defined T anywhere, you are just using it.

Comment: this question has nothing to to with Xamarin and it's not a Java lang object as you use C#.

Comment: @slfan Yes, I was thinking where is the Java part?!

Comment: @mok The param he is passing is a `Java.Lang.Object`, a `Xamarin.Android` MCW to a JNI wrapped C# class. In this case, nothing to due with his actual problem.

Comment: @SushiHangover Oh, great. I've never used that, and I should give it a try if you can pass Java Object (the root of everything in Java) like that to a c# method.

Comment: @mok https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/working_with_jni/#Class_Binding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add the generic type parameter `<T>` to your method

```
public static T Cast<T>(Object obj) where T : class
{
    var propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty("Instance");
    return propertyInfo == null ? null : propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null) as T;
}
```